# Upload a file from one server to another server

Tags: php, file-upload

I have to site on two different servers.
I want to upload a file www.myserver.com/thefile.txt to www.myotherserver.com/thesamefile.txt

Although the easiest way is to download the file to my computer and then upload, I would like to know if I can automate and make the server download it

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php, should be helpful

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The way that this site works if if you have a specific issue with a piece of code you're working on, you can ask a question for help.  The community normally frowns on people who haven't shown that they've made any attempt to solve the problem themselves.  As for your particular problem, I think you might want to look at PHP's functionality for accessing remote resources (FTP extension, CURL, etc).

Comment: try using php FTP extension, simple and safe, than any other solution.

Comment: @GordonM Sorry if my question is too vague
Its just that I wanted to accomplish the above task but couldn't find a starting point as Google understood my queries in a different way

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the other server access the URL you wrote, www.myserver.com/thefile.txt, and publish it as www.myotherserver.com/thesamefile.txt?

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh on both servers try to use scp.
`scp file ssh_login@host:/path_to_download/

Or use php ftp_* functions.

Answer (score 0):

The following code fragment should work. Just make sure that the $read_file is the url on the first server and the $write_file the location on your current server, it should not be an url but an absolute location on your server where you should be able to write.

```
<?php
function copyFile($read_file, $write_file)
{
  file_put_contents($write_file, file_get_contents($read_file));
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two options:

1. Using php ftp support, and upload the file to another server
2. Create script to myotherserver.com, make post request with file contents and save the contents using php(eg: file_put_contents)